# Deploying web apps(java Microservices) using docker vs deploying web apps in multiple ports in same VM?

Tags: docker

With respect to java Microservices deployment since we use same kind of configurations to all the apps(micro services) does it make any difference using dockers, rather than deploying on multiple ports?Because at the end apps will be down if VM is down.

Answer (score 0):

`Docker` is brilliantly suitable for microservice application deployment. You put each service into separate container and use `docker-compose` (`docker-swarm`, `k8n` or whatever) to launch your containers and link them into one isolated network (done automatically).

In such configuration you dont use `port`, but use `hostnames`. That means each container will have its own name inside network, and all requests are being done using that name. That is much more convenient comparing to use of different tcp ports.

Answer (score 0):

Putting applications inside containers are becoming the defacto standard for deployment. Docker helps in creating container images which can be used to deploy inside your cluster like kubernetes cluster.